# Small riddle: Why this isn't working on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas on why the following code perfectly 'posts' when using FF (I can see the DB updated) but fails on Chrome?

```
    $("a").click(function() {
$.post("ajax/update_count.php",  {site: 'http://mysite.com'});
     });
```

Tip: jQuery version is `jquery-1.4.3.min.js`

***Update***

The issue seems to be that when the link is clicked, a new page is loaded, which seems to be stopping the post in Chrome... Is that a possible explanation? If so, what can I do?

Comment: There are a lot of possible factors you haven't included. What's the HTML look like? What does the PHP look like? The *jQuery* version you specified too looks like the jQuery UI version, which is irrelevant.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Try checking the WebDeveloper tool in Chrome, you can see the actual request on the "Network" tab.

Comment: perhaps there are uncaught exceptions somewhere else that prevent this statement from being executed?

Comment: Is the link being followed? Try changing `function()` to `function(e)`, then adding `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of it

Comment: The statement is being executed, because I can add other events inside the 'a'.click and those are being executed...

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return false;` to the end of the function? That will cause jQuery to do `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @apsillers It also stops the propagation. Just pointing it out. That's up to the OP if they want that or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior of an `<a>`. Use this:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your code
});
```

or, if you actually want the link to load the new page, you could try:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    // Might want to put a "loading" spinner on the page here
    $.post("whatever", {}, function () {
        window.location.href = href;
    });
});
```

Might have to change it a little - maybe use `$(this).attr("href")` or `$(this).prop("href")`, not `this.href`...the differences those evaluate to may or may not work with `window.location.href` (I'm sure both do).

Comment: That stops the link, doesn't it?

Comment: @luqita - yes it stops the link.  You have to either let it follow the link to a new page OR do the post.  You cannot reliably do both with the default behavior of the link.  Instead, you would have to implement something like ianpgall has added to their answer if you want both.

Comment: @luqita Well, you didn't explain well enough what you EXPECT to happen - you just explained that it wasn't working in Chrome. Describing the situation would help. As you left that comment, I was editing my answer in case you didn't want to "stop" the link (what a coincidence). Hopefully that can do both - send the AJAX and let the link complete.